# Custom sort in Excel by first character and user-defined non-alphabetical order.

Tags: excel

I need to create my own sort order in Excel but I only want to sort by the first character of a cell. My cells look like:
T100
T101
S100
A100

I need them to auto sort with the T's first, A's second, and S's third. I have a massive number of T's in reality and I am adding unknown Txxx values to the sheet in the future, so I can't specify the entire cell value to sort by(list would constantly need updating and would be enormous).

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution might be to add a column that converts the letter to a number so `T205` becomes `1T205` and `A100` becomes `2A100`

I would structure this as:

- Column A has your values (e.g. "T101")
- Column B extracts the letter from column A and tacks on to the beginning of the value in column A `=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2),[some table],2,0) & A2`

Then sort on Column B:

[image]

Comment: Hey Ben. Thanks that is pretty helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help, @aronduncanstein!